# Have CSS Sprite "Button" Default to ON State on Page Load

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and web design in general.
I created a CSS sprite sheet of sorts that corresponds to 3 "buttons" or "links" on the page.
These buttons have a default position of OFF and a "current" position of ON.
All 3 buttons default to the OFF position when the page loads.
When you click one of them, that button changes to the ON position to let viewers know the content loaded onscreen corresponds with the button they pressed.
If they press another button, new information loads and that button is now in the ON position.
I'd like one of them to **default** to the ON position when the page is loaded.
Can someone help me do this with CSS?
Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
/*--- Set Sprite Image ---*/
#branch0,
#branch1,
#branch2
{background-image : url('images/sprite2.jpg');}
#branch_buttons #branch0{width:300px; height:65px; background-position:0 0;} 
#branch_buttons #branch1{width:300px; height:65px; background-position:left -66px;}
#branch_buttons #branch2{width:300px; height:65px; background-position:left -131px;}
/* Hover/Focus State */
#branch_buttons #branch0:hover,#branch_buttons #branch0:focus, #branch_buttons #branch0.current{width:300px; height:65px; background-position:-301px top;}
#branch_buttons #branch1:hover,#branch_buttons #branch1:focus, #branch_buttons #branch1.current{width:300px; height:65px; background-position:-301px -66px;}
#branch_buttons #branch2:hover,#branch_buttons #branch2:focus, #branch_buttons #branch2.current{width:300px; height:65px; background-position:-301px -131px;}
/* Active */
#branch_buttons #branch0:active{background-position:left -195px;}
#branch_buttons #branch1:active{background-position:left -261px;}
#branch_buttons #branch2:active{background-position:left -326px;}`
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, are you asking that on each page the sprite representing that page is "on"? If so, I would suggest either hard coding which image relates to the current page (e.g. tag one of the images as class "current" and use that to overwrite the CSS) or using Javascript.

Comment: Imagine you have 3 buttons. Each button has an UP and DOWN position.  They are all UP by default.  When you click on a button, it goes to the DOWN position and stays that way until you click a different button.  I just want one of the buttons to default to the DOWN position when the page loads. The reason being is that each button loads data into an iframe in the center of the page and when the page loads, by default it has the data displayed from one of the buttons - this is the one I want to default to DOWN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a class to the button you want to default to on (lets say add a current class) and then you would need to add the following styles (assuming your hover status is when the button is on):

```
#branch_buttons #branch0:hover,
#branch_buttons #branch0:focus,
#branch_buttons #branch0.current {width:300px; height:65px; background-position:-301px top;}
#branch_buttons #branch1:hover,
#branch_buttons #branch1:focus,
#branch_buttons #branch1.current {width:300px; height:65px; background-position:-301px -66px;}
#branch_buttons #branch2:hover,
#branch_buttons #branch2:focus,
#branch_buttons #branch2.current {width:300px; height:65px; background-position:-301px -131px;}
```

I take it you are having problems with the styles `.wayne.current` not showing your on buttons?  If so this is because you have specified your initial button styles using ids and so they won't be overridden by your activated styles - to understand why have a look at this article about [css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

**Update**

To remove the class is very simple using jQuery. First, you need to give all your buttons the same class - say `button just include the following before the closing`` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var buttons = $('.button'); // this is the selector for the buttons class

        buttons.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // this line will stop the button from posting back. 

            buttons.removeClass('current');  // this removes the current class from the buttons
            $(this).addClass('current');  // this adds the current class to the clicked buttom button
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: At the moment I'm not having any issues at all with the buttons. They all work as they should.  If I add the .current class to the wayne button (this is the one I want to default to the DOWN position), it does in fact work. When I load the page the button is in the DOWN position but when I click another button, the wayne button doesn't go back to the UP position.

Comment: yeah you'll need to use some javascript to remove the class `current` when another button is clicked

Comment: OK I'm more than happy to add some if someone can provide some examples.  I've updated the code a little bit and have edited my original post.

Comment: Do you know how to use jQuery?

Comment: HAHAHA I wish. No. I've been fumbling my way through HTML and CSS so jQuery is quite foreign.  I have been getting by modifying sample code in order to get things done.  If you were able to give me basic code or examples that pertain to this exact type of situation, that would be great.  I really would think there is some type of "ON PAGE LOAD APPLY THE HOVER STATE TO BUTTON ABC" or something like that.

Comment: @user3013140 have added a bit of jQuery to the answer

Comment: I had this question posted on this forum and one other.  I did get a working solution on the other forum. Don't know if the solution is similar to yours and seeing as it's currently working, I'd rather not start tinkering with it again to find out ;)

Comment: `#branch_buttons #branch0.current{background-position:left -195px;}
    
#branch_buttons #branch1.current{background-position:left -261px;}

#branch_buttons #branch2.current{background-position:left -326px;}

    Had to add this as well:

<script>

$(function() {
$("#branch0").addClass("current")
$("#branch_buttons a").click(function(){
$("#branch_buttons a").removeClass("current")
$(this).addClass("current")
})
})
</script>`

Comment: yeah it's pretty much the same as above but I've cached the buttons for better performance

Comment: I'd like to mark the question as answered but I'm not sure if/how I can do so.

Comment: You are able to either add your own answer or if my answer has met your needs you can click on the tick to the top left of my answer underneath the one